# Windows phone HttpClient PostAsync hang with no response

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, deadlock

I am having problem in calling the `HttpClient` post method from WP application.The `PostAsync` always hangs and does not give any response.The same code works when i try it from WPF application. Here is what I am doing:

**Server Web API code**

```
public class GameController : ApiController
{
[HttpPost]

public GameDto CreateGame(GameDto gameDto)
        {
            try
        {
            GameManager bl = new GameManager();
            gameDto = bl.CreateGame(gameDto);
            return gameDto;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Client WP8 code calling from class library**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59580");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));               
GameDto newGame = new GameDto();
                newGame.CreatedBy = 1;
            newGame.Name = txtGameName.Text;
            newGame.GameTypeId = (int)cmbGameType.SelectedValue;
             MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
             var response = await client.PostAsync<GameDto>("api/Game/CreateGame", newGame, jsonFormatter);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw on error code.
            var userDto = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GameDto>();
            //_products.CopyFrom(products);
            MessageBox.Show(userDto.Id.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where does the code block? BTW, It's pointless to catch an exception just to rethrow it.

Comment: Also `http://localhost` is the phone/emulator itself - that's almost certainly not what you want to do.

Comment: The code blocks on response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); . The exception handling is not done yet .

Http:\\localhost is dummy i use a different WebAPi URL .

Comment: `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` is a *synchronous* call that occurs on the original UI thread.

Comment: If it is synchronous at least it should execute and provide a result or throw an exception after some time . I am not getting any response back at all . The same code block works fine when i use it in WPF client.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout This 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895048/async-call-with-await-in-httpclient-never-returns?rq=1)  res.olved my issue.
Use ConfigureAwait

```
var result = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("weeklyplan")
                         .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
```

Comment: Thanks RK, this fixed my issue as well!