# httpClient GET call is not letting me return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using httpclient to make api call but when using async the class can only be void so I am trying to figure out how to return a value to my Controller and back to the view.

```
public async void GetResult(){
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient()){
 var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestMessage);
 var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
}
```

Now that I have the responseContent(value) I want to return it to my controller but every time I try to remove the void it says async only works with void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have async method the return value should always be a `Task<T>`. So if you response content is a `string`, your code would look like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetResult(){
    using(var httpClient = new HttpClient()){
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestMessage);
        return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use Task the await never finishes but when I use void the data is returned to responseContent.It hits var httpResponse = await... and never finishes. @Ion Sapoval

Comment: That's an issue with the HttpClient in ASP.NET The following questions can provide more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895048/async-call-with-await-in-httpclient-never-returns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async

Comment: Thank you so much Kenneth, for the help and the link to the other post.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of an async method must be void, `Task` or `Task<T>`.

```
 public async Task<string> GetResult(){
    using(var httpClient = new HttpClient()){
      var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestMessage);
      var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      return responseContent;
}

}
```

Comment: I don't know if you received my @ from an earlier comment but I was explaining that when I use Task the data never comes but when I use void it finishes with a value for responseContent.

Comment: And of the three, it should only be `void` in very limited circumstances (such as event handlers that can't return a value).