# Getting content from httpwebresponse exception

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

My remote server is throwing a web exception as bad request. But I know there is more information included in the error than what I get.  If I look at the details from the exception it does not list the actual content of the response.  I can see the content-type, content-length and content-encoding only.  If I run this same message through another library (such as `restsharp`) I will see detailed exception information from the remote server.  How can I get more details from the response since I know the remote server is sending them?

```
static string getXMLString(string xmlContent, string url)
{
        //string Url;
        string sResult;
        //Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserURl"] + url;

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(xmlContent);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                sResult = result;
            }
        }
        return sResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : Have you tried with a simple try-catch to see if you can get more details ?

```
try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
}
```

In my recherches in an answer for you, I noticed that in code there was something about encoding, that you didn't specified. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273205/read-text-from-response) for exemple with such code.

```
var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
{
    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx), in the doc, also.

```
// Creates an HttpWebRequest with the specified URL. 
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
// Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for the response.         
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
// Gets the stream associated with the response.
Stream receiveStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
// Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( receiveStream, encode );
Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse stream received.");
```

Have you tried with such ?

Comment: The problem I am having is the response is calling it an error on the line where the response is defined in the first place so I do not have an opportunity to capture the stream because the code has already called it an error.  (On this line: HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();)

Comment: Added proper error checking and then this solution worked.

Comment: Have exactly did you do as error checking ? Did you add a try-catch ?

Comment: An error response will usually cause WebException to be thrown. Not all error responses with message bodies will populate WebException with a response.