# c# Display web request response in a panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrrNB.png)
Hi so I want to display the response of the website in this panel, How would I go about that. I have the necessary System.Net Etc. Heres the code:

```
 private void panel7_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        }
```

Would I need to set the webresponse as a string and than pass it as string tx?

[The code of said panel]
[the code of the panel in cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCJlT.png)

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBY9w.png //the panel I want the data to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a label in the panel, then change its `label.Text` property to the response body.

To read the response body from an `HttpWebResponse`, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273252/12753809).

---

I'd also suggest you switch to the modern `HttpClient` API if you use .NET Core 3 or above:

```cs
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

Example:

```cs
using var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.contoso.com/default.html");

using var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

label.Text = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Or even simpler, if you don't need to edit the request message at all:

```cs
label.Text = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
```