# HttpClient Exception 'The response ended prematurely' when actual response length not match Content-Length header

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, httpclientfactory

#### How I can fix HttpClient Exception when the actual response length is smaller than Content-Length header

> The response ended prematurely, with at least 4508 additional bytes expected.

> The response ended prematurely, with at least 783 additional bytes expected.

I fixed this exception by reading the response content character by character until the exception happens

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = "";
try
{
    do
    {
        content += (char)streamReader.Read();
    }
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

but I didn't think this is the right or the optimal solution,

**How Can I make HttpClient ignore the Content-Length from the request header?**

Comment: Can you instead try something like:
`using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), ASCIIEncoding.ASCII))
{
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}` (borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273252/6621862)

Comment: It might seem a silly question but why is `Content-Length` bigger than the content body?

Comment: @Luke yes i tried this but its same exception happens without any output

Comment: @Peter Csala, this issue from API provider i contact them, but i tring to discover a solution or workaround for this if i blocked in this same case later, specially the request work in chrome and postman without errors